# Alternative to <rich:modalPanel> for Internet Explorer 6

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces, modalpopups

The pages of my web application are loaded really slowly on Internet Explorer 6, compared to Firefox : around 6s for IE6, 3s for Firefox.

The size of the pages are indeed a big problem in my application, but 
I also know that the `<rich:modalPanel>` is really slow on IE6 (due to DOM manipulations).

As we use a lot ot them, I think that this component may be indeed one of the reasons of this slowness...

So, is there a JSF alternative to the `<rich:modalPanel>` component?

Or eventually, do you know a javascript / jQuery modal panel code that can be easily used for a custom component in JSF?

Technical informations:

JSF 1.2 (+ Facelets) and Richfaces 3.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use a jQuery component as is in your code? You don't necessarily need a custom component for it - especially since you're using Facelets.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `<rich:modalPanel>` is root of all problems and changing to other custom components really helps. All compoments that are inside modal panel are placed in DOM but they are invisible at the begining. Try to do tests changing from modalPanel to regular one. I think that won't speed up loading time. Another test you can do is to mesure load time of page without modal panel.

For the tests I recomend use [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/) tool. It will help you mesure performance on IE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery UI Dialog is a good option. have a look at it.